# SoapUI - Getting a value from website that is randomly generated and store into header value

Tags: unit-testing, testing, groovy, automation, soapui

I am using SoapUI for automated web services testing. For me to access this particular GET endpoint, I need to get a randomly generated key by going to a website, hit generate button, and copy the key, and paste it into the Authorization header value. However, this needs to be done through automatically after a build and not manually. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure is! What have you tried? What worked? What didn't? If you would like an actual answer, have a read through [ask].

Comment: Ahh my apologies. I'm just trying to figure out if it is possible since there are many tools to test web services and don't want to be stuck with the wrong one. The material for SoapUI is overwhelming! I'm assuming I'm going to use a script to do this, but I do not know groovy yet and hoping to use selenium to get that data and somehow put that data as a header value.

Comment: You mean, the generated key can be retrieved by a http request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the api or request which generate the authorization code. For that you can use a proxy monitor tool like fiddler, chrome F12 network panel or any.
Once monitored, i hope you know how to implement it on soapui.

Or,

You can use selenium jar as an external jar and use selenium code in groovy script to open the browser > get the authorization code > getText from the element, so you can store in a variable and reuse it anywhere you want.

Hope this helped.

Comment: The Selenium way is what I was leaning towards, since I used it in a bunch of other projects, but in Java. I just need to learn how to implement it in Groovy and  to reference external jars in SoapUI. Never used anything like proxy monitors but will look into it

Comment: Nothing different between java and groovy. You can use same java codes in groovy scripts. Just make sure you have all imports. Then just a matter of copy and pasting your java codes. I mentioned proxy monitors so you can find out requests you are sending from your browser to the server.